# ¿Cómo ocultar columnas con fechas de tabla HTML con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Vuelvo nuevamente a realizar la consulta ya que me solucionaron una parte de lo que necesito.

Tengo una tabla:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tble">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>24-09-2019</th>
                <th>25-09-2019</th>
                <th>26-09-2019</th>
                <th>27-09-2019</th>
                <th>28-09-2019</th>
                <th>29-09-2019</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Gonzalo</td>
                <td>Jeria</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>DESCANSO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Marcelo</td>
                <td>Reyes</td>
                <td>DESCANSO</td>
                <td>DESCANSO</td>
                <td>DESCANSO</td>
                <td>DESCANSO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
                <td>TRABAJO</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>Soto</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
                <td>VACACIONES</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

<div class="form-inline" id="in_line">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fecha1">Ingresar Fecha desde</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="fecha_desde" id="fecha1" type="text"
            class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label
            for="fecha2">hasta</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="fecha_hasta" id="fecha2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="btn_apply" name="apply_btn">Aplicar</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Lo que necesito es filtrar sólo con `JavaScript` las fechas que según indique el usuario en los campos **desde** y **hasta**  y al darle botón aplicar se puedan filtrar las columnas de la tabla.

Simplemente necesito que se puedan ocultar.. para poder agilizar el trabajo de las fechas específicas que se filtraron.. es decir **desde Fecha 10-09-2019, hasta 31-09-2019 .. se puedan visualizar solo ese rango.. lo demás que pueda ocultarse**

¿Qué debo hacer para eso? ¿Asignarle clases a cada columna? Si alguien me puede dar indicios estaría agradecido.

Comment: Para que no reinventes la [rueda](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Intento no utilizar datatables porque la mayoría de las columnas son fechas.

Comment: No sería mejor que usaras algun calendario para eso? la forma en que se muestra la información es un poco confusa

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código realiza lo que buscas:

```js
var desde=new Date('2019-09-24');
var datos=[
    ['Gonzalo','Jeria','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','VACACIONES'],
    ['Marcelo','Reyes','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO'],
    ['Julio','Soto','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO'],
  ];
    
  $('#btn_apply').click(() => {
    var html = '';
    var info  = [];
    var f1=new Date($('#fecha1').val());
    var f2=new Date($('#fecha2').val());

    for(var per in datos){
      info[per]=`</tr><tr><td>${datos[per][0]}</td><td>${datos[per][1]}</td>`;
    }

    while(f1<=f2){
      html+=`<th>${`0${f1.getUTCDate()}`.slice(-2)}/${`0${f1.getUTCMonth()+1}`.slice(-2)}/${f1.getUTCFullYear()}</th>`;
      
      var diff=2+((f1-desde)/(1000*60*60*24))|0;
      for(var per in datos){
        info[per]+=`<td>${ diff<2? 'sin datos' : datos[per][diff] || 'sin datos' }</td>`;
      }
      f1.setDate(f1.getDate() + 1);
    }

    $('#tble').html(`<thead><tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th>${html}</tr></thead><tbody>${info.join('')}</tbody>`);
  });

  $('#btn_apply').click();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-inline" id="in_line">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fecha1">Ingresar Fecha desde</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="fecha_desde" id="fecha1" type="date"
            class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2" value="2019-09-24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label
            for="fecha2">hasta</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="fecha_hasta" id="fecha2" type="date" value="2019-09-29" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="btn_apply" name="apply_btn">Aplicar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tble">

</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Para que funcione hacen falta un par de cosas:

En lugar de que los datos se carguen en una tabla, deben cargarse en un array javascript:

```
var datos=[
        ['Gonzalo','Jeria','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','VACACIONES'],
        ['Marcelo','Reyes','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO'],
        ['Julio','Soto','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','DESCANSO','TRABAJO','TRABAJO'],
];
```

Luego debe guardarse en una variable la fecha desde la que inician los datos:

```
var desde=new Date('2019-09-24');
```

El enfoque de la solución es que en lugar de ocultar columnas agregando clases y código css, se puede generar el contenido de la tabla con jquery a partir de las fechas ingresadas, evitando tener problemas de lógica,

Cuando se ingresen fechas en las que no se tengan datos el ejemplo mostrará `"sin datos"` (el mensaje se puede cambiar en el código).

De esa forma se pueden filtrar los datos por fechas para mostrarse en una tabla, saludos.

Comment: excelente tu aporte the-breaker.. lo voy a probar, me olvidé mencionar que usaba datepicker en los inputs de fechas desde-hasta, no hay problema si trabajo con esos a diferencia del date de html ?

Comment: @h6gignacio si, no hay problema, solo lo cambie para mostrar el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma:

- Buscamos todas las columnas de la tabla (`eg: $('#tble > thead th')`)
- Controlamos solo aquellas que solo te interesa (`eg: no las class="skip"`)
- Obtenemos las fecha que representa esta columna (`eg $tr.text().split('-');...`)
- Obtenemos todas las celdas de dicha columna (`eg: $('#tble > thead th:nth-of-type(${idx+1}), #tble > tbody td:nth-of-type(${idx+1})');`)
- Si la fecha es anterior o posterior a la establecida en los filtros, ocultamos todas las celdas de dicha columna (`eg: $cels.addClass('hide')`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  // Buscamos los filtros
  let $from = $('#fecha1');
  let $to = $('#fecha2');

  //
  function applyFilter() {
    // Obtenemos las fechas
    var dateFrom = $from.val() ? new Date($from.val()) : false;
    var dateTo = $to.val() ? new Date($to.val()) : false;

    // Buscamos las columnas
    $('#tble > thead th').each((idx, tr) => {
      let $tr = $(tr);

      // Salteamos las columnas que no nos interesan
      if ($tr.hasClass('skip')) return;

      // Buscamos las celdas de la columna
      $cels = $(`#tble > thead th:nth-of-type(${idx+1}), #tble > tbody td:nth-of-type(${idx+1})`);
      // Les quitamos la clase que las oculta
      $cels.removeClass('hide');

      // Obtenemos la fecha de la columna
      let parts = $tr.text().split('-');
      let date = new Date(Date.UTC(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]));

      // Si es anterior o posterior, la ocultamos
      if ((dateFrom && date < dateFrom) || (dateTo && date > dateTo)) $cels.addClass('hide');
    });
  }

  $('#btn_apply').on('click', applyFilter);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tble">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="skip">Nombre</th>
        <th class="skip">Apellido</th>
        <th>24-09-2019</th>
        <th>25-09-2019</th>
        <th>26-09-2019</th>
        <th>27-09-2019</th>
        <th>28-09-2019</th>
        <th>29-09-2019</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Gonzalo</td>
        <td>Jeria</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>DESCANSO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marcelo</td>
        <td>Reyes</td>
        <td>DESCANSO</td>
        <td>DESCANSO</td>
        <td>DESCANSO</td>
        <td>DESCANSO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
        <td>TRABAJO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Julio</td>
        <td>Soto</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
        <td>VACACIONES</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

<div class="form-inline" id="in_line">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fecha1">Ingresar Fecha desde</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="fecha_desde" id="fecha1" type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2" value="2019-09-24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="fecha2">hasta</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="fecha_hasta" id="fecha2" type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker2" value="2019-09-29">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="btn_apply" name="apply_btn">Aplicar</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```